# Is there a single word that means "a purchase order and all invoices connected to it?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on a database that contains invoices and purchase orders. It would help tremendously if there was a single word that had this meaning.

Is there one, or is there anything close?

Comment: You'll probably have to look at your business processes to see. How do purchase orders relate to other things e.g. tenders, equipment requests, purchases, customer orders, projects, departments? It might be referred to as a purchase or transaction, although they may have other meanings.

Comment: Does it also contain delivery notes, receipts, 'to follow' notifications and amendment documentation?

Comment: I feel pretty confident in saying "no, there isn't one". If there was an obscure, little known word that meant that there would be no point in using it because nobody would know what it meant. If you are naming a database table I strongly recommend "InvoicesAndPurchaseOrders".

Comment: **Purchase history** https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q="Purchase+history"&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: You could refer to invoices and purchase orders collectively as **instructions**. 

That said, computerized accounting systems have been in existence for almost eighty years now. And before that, there were filing cabinets. There are probably any number of labeling schemes already out there. 

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filing_cabinet

Comment: **purchase orders and related invoices**. Google it, you'll see. The term related is the most used one: contracts and related invoices, etc. Just another example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call all such computer records / physical documents collectively the...

> [**audit trail**](https://www.auditboard.com/blog/what-is-an-audit-trail/)
> *a detailed, chronological record whereby accounting records, project details, **or other financial data** are tracked and traced.*

Comment: Or less formally, "the paperwork" associated with anything.

Comment: "paperwork" might be well on the way to becoming a [skeuomorph!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeuomorph) Increasingly, audit trails *only* exist in electronic format, with no "**paper** trail".

Comment: Anymore than there's a dial on your phone or a book on your disk.

Comment: "dial" on the phone! When posting the above, I spent well over a minute trying to think of a phone-based example. I knew there was a really good one, but it wouldn't come to me. *Giving someone a bell, Holding the line,* and *hanging up* are all in that general territory, but ***dialing*** is the clincher. Although as a matter of fact my 30-year-old daughter recently bought herself a "retro" landline telephone complete with dial and mouthpiece on a cable. She hardly ever uses it though (she prefers her smartphone anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Documents**

> a piece of written, printed, or electronic matter that provides information or evidence or that serves as an official record.

Unless there are other documents, this is clear and extensible. If you have other non-financial documents but these are the only financial, you can qualify with *financial documents* in camel/snake case.

[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=documents%20definition)